# NiFi JsonPathReader parsing array problem

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm attempting to parse JSON to csv using the GetFile --> CovertRecord --> PutFile processors. My sample JSON looks like:

```
[
    {
        "id": "A1",
        "value": "blue",
        "num": [5,6,7]
    }, 
    {
        "id": "B2",
        "value": "red",
        "num": [1,2,3]
    }, 
    {
        "id": "C3",
        "value": "green",
        "num": [4,8,9]
    }
]
```

After configuring the JsonPathReader & CSVRecordSetWriter controllers, I can successfully parse the JSON with the csv output looking like:

```
id, value,  num
A1, blue,   [5, 6, 7]
B2, red,    [1, 2, 3]
C3, green,  [4, 8, 9]
```

The Avro Schema in the JsonPathReader configuration looks like:

```
{
    "type" : "record",
    "namespace" : "data",
    "name" : "stuff",
    "fields" : [
        {"name" : "id" , "type" : "string"},
        {"name" : "value" , "type" : "string"},
        {"name" : "num" , "type" : {"type" : "array", "items" : "int"}}
     ]
}
```

However I ultimately need the csv output to look like:

```
id, value,  num
A1, blue,   5
A1, blue,   6
A1, blue,   7
B2, red,    1
B2, red,    2
B2, red,    3
C3, green,  4
C3, green,  8
C3, green,  9
```

Is this possible using the standard NiFi processors & controllers? I'm trying to avoid building a custom processor.

Comment: You can use ExecuteScript processor for this types of transformation. It's simple and fast if you'll write on JavaScript or Groovy

Comment: It turns out the JSON structure was more complex than I anticipated and required that two csv files be spun off. I ended up building a custom processor.